# Out of Range values for "commrate" at column 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I created this table using the following SQL script,

```
CREATE TABLE part
(Partno    CHAR(4) PRIMARY KEY,
 Partdesc  VARCHAR(20),
 Onhand    INTEGER,
 Partclass CHAR(2) check (Partclass IN ('AP','HW','KI','SP')),
 Unitprice DECIMAL(6,2)
);


CREATE TABLE salesrep
(Srepno     CHAR(3),
 Srepname   VARCHAR(25),
 Srepstreet VARCHAR(30),
 Srepcity   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 Srepprov   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 Sreppcode  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 Totcomm    DECIMAL(8,2),
 Commrate   DECIMAL(3,2),
 CONSTRAINT pkslsrep PRIMARY KEY (Srepno)
);


CREATE TABLE customer
(Custno     CHAR(3),
 Custname   VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
 Custstreet VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 Custcity   VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
 Custprov   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 Custpcode  VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
 Disc       DECIMAL(3,1),
 Balance    DECIMAL(7,2),
 Credlimit  DECIMAL(5),
 Srepno     CHAR(3),
 CONSTRAINT pkcustno PRIMARY KEY (Custno),
 CONSTRAINT fksrepno FOREIGN KEY (Srepno) REFERENCES salesrep(Srepno)
);


CREATE TABLE orders
(Orderno   CHAR(5) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
 Orderdate DATE,
 Custno    CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fkordercust FOREIGN KEY (Custno) REFERENCES customer (Custno)
);


CREATE TABLE orderprod
(Orderno    CHAR(5),
 Partno     CHAR(4),
 Orderqty   INTEGER CHECK (Orderqty>0),
 Orderprice DECIMAL(7,2),
 CONSTRAINT pkorderprod PRIMARY KEY (Orderno, Partno),
 CONSTRAINT fkordprdord FOREIGN KEY (Orderno) REFERENCES orders(Orderno),
 CONSTRAINT fkordprdpar FOREIGN KEY (Partno) REFERENCES part(Partno)
);


CREATE TABLE invoice
( Invno     CHAR(6),
  Invdate   DATE,
  Orderno    CHAR(5),
  CONSTRAINT fkinvoice FOREIGN KEY (Orderno) REFERENCES orders(Orderno),
  CONSTRAINT pkinvoice PRIMARY KEY (Invno)
);


CREATE TABLE invprod
( Invno     CHAR(6),
  Partno    CHAR(4),
  Shipqty   INTEGER CHECK (Shipqty>0),
  CONSTRAINT fkinvoic FOREIGN KEY (Invno) REFERENCES invoice(Invno),
  CONSTRAINT fkpart FOREIGN KEY (Partno) REFERENCES part(Partno)
);
```

Then I tried to add some records using the following script,

```
INSERT INTO part(Partno, Partdesc, Onhand, Partclass, Unitprice) VALUES('1542','Exhaust Fans', '32', 'KI', '259.99');
INSERT INTO part(Partno, Partdesc, Onhand, Partclass, Unitprice) VALUES('1489','Washing Machine IFB', '10', 'AP', '1499.99');
INSERT INTO part(Partno, Partdesc, Onhand, Partclass, Unitprice) VALUES('1378','Cleaning Kit', '40', 'HW', '19.99');
INSERT INTO part(Partno, Partdesc, Onhand, Partclass, Unitprice) VALUES('1256','Soccer Ball', '15', 'SP', '20.99');

INSERT INTO salesrep(Srepno, Srepname, Srepstreet, Srepcity, Srepprov, Sreppcode, Totcomm, Commrate) VALUES('125','Dwayne Johnson', 'Aidelaide Street', 'Toronto', 'ON', 'L6T7U7', '2566.58', '12');
INSERT INTO salesrep(Srepno, Srepname, Srepstreet, Srepcity, Srepprov, Sreppcode, Totcomm, Commrate) VALUES('147','Sean Mathews', 'Hurontario Street', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L6Y5H7', '3400.89', '15');

INSERT INTO customer(Custno, Custname, Custstreet, Custcity, Custprov, Custpcode, Disc, Balance, Credlimit, Srepno) VALUES('589','Ankur Kaushal', 'Listcreek Road', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L6P2N7', '20.0','0.00', '500', '125');
INSERT INTO customer(Custno, Custname, Custstreet, Custcity, Custprov, Custpcode, Disc, Balance, Credlimit, Srepno) VALUES('458','Iqbal Jassal', 'Bayridge Dr', 'Brampton', 'ON', 'L7U5D5', '10.0','100.00', '500', '147');

INSERT INTO orders(Orderno, Orderdate, Custno) VALUES('14587','2011-11-09', '125' );
INSERT INTO orders(Orderno, Orderdate, Custno) VALUES('11547','2011-11-07', '125' );

INSERT INTO orderprod(Orderno, Partno, Orderqty, Orderprice) VALUES('14587','1256', '2', '41.98' );
INSERT INTO orderprod(Orderno, Partno, Orderqty, Orderprice) VALUES('11547','1489', '1', '1499.99' );

INSERT INTO invoice(Invno, Invdate, Orderno) VALUES('578977','2011-11-09', '14587');

INSERT INTO invprod(Invno, Partno, Shipqty) VALUES('578977','1256', '2');
```

But I am encountering '**Script line: 12    Out of range value for column 'Commrate' at row 1**
'
Any mistake I am making?

Comment: Please consider posting only the code/etc. that's actually relevant to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Decimal (3,2) means that the maximum value allowed is 9.99

Take a look at the official manual

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

`DECIMAL(3,2)` has 3 digits, with 2 decimal precision.  This means you can only store a value up to 9.99

MySQL documentation on [DECIMAL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)